# How to make GraphViz ladder diagram flows straight

Tags: graphviz, dot

The graphviz code below generates a ladder diagram, but flow3 is curved. This only happens when the edge crosses a vertical line.  How can I make flow3 straight and horizontal?  I tried experimenting with the splines attribute with no success.  How can the code be changed to force a straight line through other objects?

[image]

```
digraph ladder { ranksep=".1"; nodesep=".1";

# Define the defaults
  node [shape=point fontsize=10]
  edge [dir=none fontsize=10]

# Column labels
  a [shape=none]
  b [shape=none]
  c [shape=none]
  d [shape=none]

# Draw the 4 column headings, no line
  { rank=same; edge[style=invis] a -> b -> c -> d   }

# Draw the columns
  a -> a1 [style=invis]
  b -> b1 [style=invis]
  c -> c1 [style=invis]
  d -> d1 [style=invis]
  a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
  b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
  c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
  d1 -> d2 -> d3 -> d4 [weight=1000 label="   "]

# Now each step in the ladder
  { rank=same; a1 -> b1 [dir=forward label="Flow1"]  }
  { rank=same; b2 -> c2 [dir=forward label="Flow2"]  }
  { rank=same; b3 -> d3 [dir=forward label="Flow3"]  }
  { rank=same; c4 -> d4 [dir=back label="Flow4"]  }
}
```

## EDIT with updates per comments.

Running GraphViz version 2.38.0.

The splines attribute changes the results slightly.  Only the first line of code is changed, like this:

```
digraph ladder { ranksep=".1"; nodesep=".1"; splines=false;
```

With this result when splines are disabled:

[image]

Comment: What GraphViz version are you using? Can you also add your experiment with "splines" attribute? From the docs, I'd assume that you have to set it to "false" for the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Insac.  I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Can I suggest you to post an issue to the Graphwiz team? There is a related issue about "circuitous routes" (link in my answer) but they refer to edge with labels impacting other edges (in this case the impacted edge is the one with the label)

Comment: I've added a comment to the existing issue, linking to this question. It may be useful also for them as this graph seems a bit simpler than the one cited in the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this and for linking the circuitous routes issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible solution.  Also a hack.  It involves splitting the curved flow into multiple smaller straight flows.

Change this:

```
  { rank=same; b3 -> d3 [dir=forward label="Flow3"]  }
```

To This:

```
  {
    rank=same;
    b3 -> c3 [dir=none]
    c3 -> d3 [dir=forward label="Flow3"]
  }
```

Also made some other unrelated improvements to make the nodes invisible and the vertical edges dotted. So the complete code is this:

```
digraph ladder { ranksep=".1"; nodesep=".1";

# Define the defaults
  node [shape=point fontsize=10]
  edge [dir=none fontsize=10]

# Column labels
  a [shape=none]
  b [shape=none]
  c [shape=none]
  d [shape=none]

# Draw the 4 column headings, no line
  { rank=same; edge[style=invis] a -> b -> c -> d   }

# Draw the columns
  node [style=invis]
  a -> a1 [style=invis]
  b -> b1 [style=invis]
  c -> c1 [style=invis]
  d -> d1 [style=invis]
  a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 [style=dotted weight=1000 label="   "]
  b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4 [style=dotted weight=1000 label="   "]
  c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 [style=dotted weight=1000 label="   "]
  d1 -> d2 -> d3 -> d4 [style=dotted weight=1000 label="   "]

# Now each step in the ladder
  { rank=same; a1 -> b1 [dir=forward label="Flow1"]  }
  { rank=same; b2 -> c2 [dir=forward label="Flow2"]  }
  {
    rank=same;
    b3 -> c3 [dir=none]
    c3 -> d3 [dir=forward label="Flow3"]
  }
  { rank=same; c4 -> d4 [dir=back label="Flow4"]  }
}
```

And the resulting ladder diagram is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the issue seems to be that edge `b3 -> d3` is trying to avoid its own label (maybe related to this [issue](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/issues/138)).

So here is an horrible hack to solve the issue:

```
 digraph ladder { ranksep=".1"; nodesep=".1"; splines="line";

 # Define the defaults
   node [shape=point fontsize=10]
   edge [dir=none fontsize=10]

 # Column labels
   a [shape=none]
   b [shape=none]
   c [shape=none]
   d [shape=none]

 # Draw the 4 column headings, no line
   { rank=same; edge[style=invis] a -> b -> c -> d   }

 # Draw the columns
   a -> a1 [style=invis]
   b -> b1 [style=invis]
   c -> c1 [style=invis]
   d -> d1 [style=invis]

   a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
   b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
   c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> c4 [weight=1000 label="   "]
   d1 -> d2 -> d3 -> d4 [weight=1000 label="   "]

  # inserted a label for the node that "pretends" to be the edge label
   c3 [xlabel="Flow3"]

 # Now each step in the ladder
   { rank=same; a1 -> b1 [dir=forward label="Flow1"]  }
   { rank=same; b2 -> c2 [dir=forward label="Flow2"]  }
   { rank=same; b3 -> d3 [dir=forward ]  } #removed the label
   { rank=same; c4 -> d4 [dir=back label="Flow4"]  }
 }
```

The changes are:

1. added the `spline=line` directive
2. removed the "Flow3" label from the edge (that modification turned back the edge to a straight line)
3. added a "Flow3" label to the `c3` node

And that's the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you insac.  I've found another solution I will post as an answer.